# Django ModelAdmin not registered

Tags: python, django, django-admin

First, I want to inform that I did check other related questions but their solutions were very simple (improper registration, settings, etc.). This problem is weird in a way that I haven't faced in 3+ years of developing with Django. So here comes:

I have an app that's 90% celery tasks, so it only has **two models**. They are *simple*. I have two ModelAdmin classes defined in the admin.py of the app, one for each model. These are *simple* as well. They are both registered properly. The app is in the INSTALLED_APPS.

All kosher and without any customization of templates, tags or forms, just a plain admin.py:

```
from myapp.models import (Something, OtherModel)

class SomethingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # admin config ...

class OtherModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass # Trying anything at this point...

admin.site.register(Something, SomethingAdmin)
admin.site.register(OtherModel, OtherModelAdmin)
```

So simple it cannot fail, but it does: one of them doesn't show up in the admin. It's simply not registered (404 on manual url access). The other one does show up, and does work properly.
Validation on that *invisible admin* works because when I add a strange value to its list_display, Django does raise the proper exception (ImproperlyConfigured). So it does reads it, it just fails to register it. If I comment the *visible one* out, the app is simply removed from the admin (of course, it *thinks* no modeladmins).

So, in short, one of the ModelAdmins is invisible, while the other one *in the same file* and with nearly identical configuration, isn't. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Answers to a few suggestions I expect: Yes, the model is working properly (and heavily unit tested), and I have created/saved instances and they are in the db. Yes, I did restart the server. Yes, the computer is plugged in and it's currently on. :)

Comment: What are the actual names of the Model and ModelAdmin classes? Could it be that it's already registered under a different app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was in the structure: *models* was a package, instead of the more usual module. It seems that **even if you make the model available at package level** (import it in **init**.py), Django still doesn't know in what app it should be included.

What you need to do is specify the `app_label` in its Meta class. So the model now becomes:

```
from django.db import models

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'someapp'
        # other meta attrs
    # Model attrs ...
```

Odd that it needs to be specified, when the model is available in the usual `models.SomeModel` namespace, but at least the solution's simple enough.

BTW, as you can guess the other model *did include* this Meta attr, I just didn't notice it before. LOL.